# How to get monthly users Month by Month in Google Analytics for Spreadsheets?

Tags: google-analytics, google-sheets

I am using the (wonderful) Google Analytics plugin for Google Spreadsheets and I want a list of New Users month by month. I can easily query all new users from one date to another, but I want them "bucketed" per month. How do I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use ga:month as one of the dimensions and ga:mewUsers as metric.
check this url for google documentation about the dimensions : https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets